# Find an example of an even function such that $f'(0) = 0$ and $f(0)$ is not a local maximum / minimum of the function

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

> Find an example of an even function such that $f'(0) = 0$ and $f(0)$
>   is not a local maximum / minimum of the function

I have been thinking about it for a while and I do not think that such function does exist. If we want the function not to have an extremum at $x = 0$, then the only possibility we are left with is that $(0,f(0))$ is an inflection point of the function. It means that the $n$th derivative ($n$ - odd) does not equal zero and all of its previous derivatives do. But then, since $n$ is odd, then the function, too, is odd - and so this does not work.

Can you think of an example of such function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$ f(x) = x^2 \sin \left( \frac{1}{x^2} \right)  $$
when $x \neq 0,$ also $f(0) = 0$

Comment: How did you come to this solution? You simply guessed it or used some kind of an alogithm to find it?

Comment: @Aemilius Well it's part of the famously known counter examples in mathematics. Also notice that if $f$ is $C^2$ then $f''(-x)=f''(x)$ and locally $f(x)=f(0)+x^2f''(0)/2$ is a local extrema, thus a counter example would exploit $f''$ does not exists.

Comment: One more question - why can we use this function? It is not differentiable at $x = 0$ because it is not continuous, thus why are we allowed to use its derivative at $x=0$?

Comment: @Aemilius given your comment, I think you ought to write down, **very carefully,** a proof that this thing is continuous,  has a derivative at the origin, and the derivative at the origin does turn out to be zero.

Comment: @zwim, no, the function is bounded between $x^2$ and $- x^2$ at the origin. The value at the origin is $0.$ We then write the fraction that defines the derivative at the origin...

Comment: There are plenty of examples which are $C^2$ - such as $f(x) = x^{8} \sin(1/x^2)$.  It just happens in those cases that $f''(0) = 0$.

Comment: In fact, I think $e^{-1/x^2} \sin(1/x^2)$ would even be $C^\infty$.

Comment: @WillJagy
The problem is that I do not feel comfortable with taking the derivative of a function at point $x = 0$ which is not differentiable at $x = 0$, since it is not continuous at $0$. I still cannot comprehend why we can do this..

Comment: @Aemilius Set $f(0)=0$ then $|f(x)-f(0)|\le x^2\to 0$ and $|f'(0)|=\lim |f(x)/x|\le x\to 0$ so $f'(0)=0$.